# Are the converses of the following mentioned theorems also true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus

Let $X$ be any non-empty set

Let $Y$ be any non-empty set

Let $P(m)$ be any propositional statement containing object $m \in X$

Let $Q(n)$ be any propositional statement containing object $n \in Y$

Let $R(m,n)=P(m)\ \wedge\ Q(n)$

Then we know that the following two Theorems are correct:

---

First Theorem is the following:

$\Bigg\{[\forall\ m \in X,\ P(m)]\ \wedge\ [\forall\ n \in Y,\ Q(n)]\Bigg\}$
implies
$\Bigg\{[\forall\ m \in X,\forall\ n \in Y] [P(m)\ \wedge\ Q(n) ]\Bigg\}$

**QUESTION 1:** **Is the converse of first theorem also true?**

---

Second Theorem is the following:

$\Bigg\{[\exists\ m \in X,\ P(m)]\ \wedge\ [\exists\ n \in Y,\ Q(n)]\Bigg\}$
implies
$\Bigg\{[\exists\ m \in X,\exists\ n \in Y] [P(m)\ \wedge\ Q(n) ]\Bigg\}$

**QUESTION 2:** **Is the converse of second theorem also true?**

---

**Showing converse of first theorem is not necessarily true**

$\Bigg\{[\forall\ m \in X,\forall\ n \in Y] [P(m)\ \wedge\ Q(n) ]\Bigg\} \tag 1$

$\Rightarrow$
$\Bigg\{[m \in X\ \wedge\ n \in Y] \Rightarrow  [P(m)\ \wedge\ Q(n)]\Bigg\} \tag 2$

does not necessarily imply
$\Bigg\{[m \in X\ \Rightarrow\ P(m)] \wedge\  [n \in Y\ \Rightarrow\ Q(n)]\Bigg\} \tag 3$

$\Rightarrow$
$\Bigg\{[\forall\ m \in X,\ P(m)]\ \wedge\ [\forall\ n \in Y,\ Q(n)]\Bigg\} \tag 4$

By making a truth table, we can see that the statement in second line of proof **does not necessarily imply** the statement in third line of proof.

Therefore, the statement in first line of proof **does not necessarily imply** the statement in fourth line of proof.

Thus we have shown that the converse of first theorem is not necessarily true.

---

**Am I correct? If no, please point out the mistakes in the above proof.**

Comment: @TankutBeygu: Do you mean $(1)$ does not imply $(2)$?

Comment: I've retracted my comment; there seems no problem at that.

Answer (score 1):

The first converse is true if both sets are nonempty or both sets are empty.

The second one is always true.

---

The statement you say is not necessarily an implication actually is. Let me prove you the first converse provided both sets are nonempty (I don't go through your rewriting with $\implies$)

Assume $\Bigg\{[\forall\ m \in X,\forall\ n \in Y] [P(m)\ \wedge\ Q(n) ]\Bigg\}$.

Let $m\in X$. $Y$ is nonempty so there exists some $n\in Y$. Consider it. Then by assumption, $P(m) \wedge Q(n)$. In particular, $P(m)$. We have shown $\forall m\in X, P(m)$.

Let $n\in Y$. $X$ is nonempty so there exists some $m\in X$. Consider it. Then by assumption, $P(m) \wedge Q(n)$. In particular, $Q(n)$. We have shown $\forall n\in Y, P(n)$.

Finally we have shown $(\forall m\in X, P(m))\wedge (\forall n\in Y, P(n))$.

Comment: Actually, I meant both sets are non-empty... But I don't think that the first converse is true... Please have a look at the edit of this question...

Comment: Edited to address your edit

Comment: (3) implies (2)... But (2) does not necessarily imply (3). Consider:

Comment: $m \in X$ is true..... $n \in Y$ is false...... $P(m)$ is false..... $Q(m)$ is false.....

Comment: In this case,  (2) is true and (3) is false. So (2) does not imply (3).

Comment: That's the danger of working with unquantified $\implies$ symbols. $[m\in X \wedge n \in Y] \implies [P(m) \wedge Q(n)]$ is not a proper logical statement. You need to prefix it with a $\forall m\in X \forall n\in Y$ so that the variables $x$ and $y$ are bound. We often omit it by abuse of notation but it can lead to misunderstandings like here.

Comment: The problem being that here $m\in X$ and $n\in Y$ can't be false. Unless of course $X$ or $Y$ are empty (which indeed would make the statement false, as I told you before).

Comment: "so that the variables x and y are bound" What do you mean by that?

Comment: bound, i.e. quantified (with $\forall$ or $\exists$) quantifiers. You can't leave unquantified variables in a standalone mathematical statement. Explanations on Bound variables and free variables there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables

Comment: $[m\in X \wedge n \in Y] \implies [P(m) \wedge Q(n)]$ *is* a "proper logical statement" and is equivalent to the same, "prefixed with" $∀m ∀n$ (and not "$\forall m\in X \forall n\in Y$"). These are the [rules of introduction and elimination of $\forall$ in natural deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction#First_and_higher-order_extensions).

Comment: @AnneBauval Natural deduction, which I just discovered thanks to you, is certainly not a standard among mathematicians, all the less among undergraduate students which I have a feeling OP is one. Do you teach that to undergraduates in Toulouse?

Comment: @justt I never taught it formally but I used to practise it intuitively, before discovering it 15 years ago on Wikipedia. I wish my students were as skilled as this OP

Answer (score 1):

Your $(2)\not\Rightarrow(3)$ is correct and your truth table must have shown you that the implication fails exactly when
$$(n\notin Y\land m\in X\land\neg P(m))\lor(m\notin X\land n\in Y\land\neg Q(n)).$$
This indicates that the counterexamples to the converse of theorem 1 are exactly  when either $Y=\varnothing$ and $\exists m\in X\;\neg P(m)$, or $X=\varnothing$ and $\exists n\in Y\;\neg Q(n)$.

The same resoning (with truth tables) certainly showed you that theorem 2 and its converse are "true", as well as theorem 1.